# Can't make a function that restricts players from putting a piece wherever they want. "Connect Four"

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to make a beginner project of a "Connect Four" game. the project has a backend using Node.JS with MySQL, using API's. I mostly did everything, I just can't achieve the logic that makes players not being able to put a piece wherever they want.

```
      for (let i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
        let divCell = document.createElement('div');
        divCell.className = 'divCell';
        divCells.push(divCell);
        divCell.i = i;
        divCell.onclick = () => {
          if (divCell.classList.contains('played')) {
            return;
          }

          let column = divCell.i % 7;
          if (divCells[column].classList.contains('played')) {
            return;
          }

          let row = 5;
          while (row >= 0 && divCells[row * 7 + column].classList.contains('played')) {
            row--;
          }
          if (row < 0) {
            return;
          }

          divCells[row * 7 + column].classList.add('played');
          if (currentPlayer == 1) {
            currentPlayer = 2;
          } else {
            currentPlayer = 1;
          }
          sendHttpGetRequest('api/play_cell?username='+username+'&password='+password+'&id='+gameId+'&cell='+i, (result) => {
            if (result) {

            }
          });
        };
        divBoard.appendChild(divCell);
      }
    }
```

the code creates 42 divs dynamically, pushes it into an array, and gives every cell a parameter 'i' which declares what cell it is. the rest of code, well, you can see it. I hope you can help me understand what am I doing wrong. to be clear there are no errors in the log or the terminal. the css is just a cursor of not allowed.

I am sorry if I used the wrong syntax for this question this is my first post.
Thanks!

I have tried figuring out maybe I am doing something wrong with the loops but I just couldn't figure it out.